# webscraping with rvest: Replace missing values of html_nodes with NA

Tags: r, web-scraping, nested-lists, rvest

I scrape [this](https://www.journals.elsevier.com/academic-pediatrics/editorial-board) page to obtain (1) names, (2) roles/editorial titles, and (3) *institutional affiliation* of each person listed there.

The problem is that some people do not have an *institutional affiliation*. I want to replace these missing values with `NA`, but none of my attempts has worked yet.

I would be grateful for your help! Here is my code so far:

```
    journal_url <- "https://www.journals.elsevier.com/academic-pediatrics/editorial-board"
    webpage <- xml2::read_html(journal_url)
    webpage <- rvest::html_nodes(webpage, "div.publication-editors")

    editorsnodes <- rvest::html_children(webpage)

    titlesnodesnum <- which(rvest::html_attr(editorsnodes, "class") == "publication-editor-type")
    titles <- editorsnodes[titlesnodesnum]
    titles <- rvest::html_text(titles)
    titles <- trimws(titles)
    titlesnodesnum <- c(titlesnodesnum, length(editorsnodes)+1) #identify the last record

    editors <- lapply(2:length(titlesnodesnum), function(n){
      start<- titlesnodesnum[n-1]+1  #starting node in subcategory
      end <- titlesnodesnum [n]-1   #ending node in subcategory
      names <- editorsnodes[start:end]
      names <- rvest::html_nodes(names, "div.publication-editor-name")
      names <- rvest::html_text(names)
      names <- trimws(names)
    })
```

My main attempt was to insert a `for`-loop within the `editors <- lapply([...])` part with something like `if(length(names) == 0) names <- NA`, but nothing worked.

P. S. My data structure may seem complex, but I need to retain the structure of a nested list for this purpose (for the background, see [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64188257/r-webscraping-various-div-classes-into-lists-with-sub-elements) I had posted before - and from where I got much of the code below).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. I used `toString` to change the xml nodeset to a string, extracted all `<div class="publication-editor">` and checked whether each of them have one `<span class="publication-editor-affiliation">`; when they did not, the combination of `lapply`and `str_extract` led to a `NA`.

Here is the code, for the record.

```
    affiliations <- lapply(2:length(titlesnodesnum), function(n){
      start<- titlesnodesnum[n-1]+1  #starting node in subcategory
      end <- titlesnodesnum [n]-1   #ending node in subcategory
      affiliations <- toString(editorsnodes[start:end])
      affiliations <- stringr::str_extract_all(affiliations, "(?<=<div class=\"publication-editor\")[\\S\\s]*?(?=<div class=\"clearfix\">)")
      affiliations <- lapply(affiliations, function(x) stringr::str_extract(x, "(?<=<span class=\"publication-editor-affiliation\" itemprop=\"affiliation\">).*?(?=</span>)"))
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

The attached sub-routine will extract the affiliations, if any, of the people listed on the webpage. For those without an affiliation, the code will insert an "NA".  One of the issues with your code was names was not scraping node "span.publication-editor-affiliation".  I also used "is_empty()" to detect whether there was no affiliation listed.

```
affiliations <- lapply(2:length(titlesnodesnum), function(n){
  start<- titlesnodesnum[n-1]+1  #starting node in subcategory
  end <- titlesnodesnum [n]-1   #ending node in subcategory
  affiliations <- editorsnodes[start:end]
  affiliations <- rvest::html_nodes(affiliations, "span.publication-editor-affiliation")
  affiliations <- rvest::html_text(affiliations)
  if (purrr::is_empty(affiliations)){affiliations=NA} 
  affiliation <- trimws(affiliations)
})
```

Comment: Wonderful, almost there, thank you! It still seems to miss one person though (the 4th Associate Editor named J. L. Raphael) who lacks an affiliation, but there is no `NA` given to him. I think the reason is that he simply does not have a node `span.publication-editor-affiliation`. Would you happen to know how to fix it? I would be very grateful!